# django pillow loading multiple images is slow

Tags: python, django, image, performance, python-imaging-library

I am fetching images from an api and rendering in django app. Loading images this way is really slow.

template tag

```py
def url(id):
    url = f'http://api.com/image?id={id}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    data = BytesIO()
    img.save(data, "PNG")
    data.seek(0)
    encoded_img_data = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
    return encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8')
```

html

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{row.image_md5|url}}" />
```

it works, but it's 1 second for loading an image. Is there a way to load all images faster this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked what the bottleneck is?
Could be that the API is just very slow.

You can time it with this for example:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
url = f'http://api.com/image?id={id}'
response = requests.get(url)
end_time = time.time() - start_time
print(end_time)
```

Comment: it took 16 seconds to fetch 6 images, 2 images with 4.5 sec and the rest with 1.2 -1.5

Comment: Well isn't the problem with your API then?
If we take 1.2 seconds for 4 images and 4.5 sec for 2, it's: 4.8 + 9 = 13.8 seconds.
That's already 85% of the whole loading time.

What you could do is load the images with ajax and show a placeholder first, then cache the result if it needs to be shown more than once.  

Another solution could be to use a cron/automatic task to pull all the images you need, then cache it.